# sum values in sub array in foreach

Tags: php, sub-array

i have code:

```
foreach ($result as $value)  {  // for each person do

   foreach ($reasons as $key => $val) {  //for each reason do:

     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  //make sum for each reason 

        $array[$row['reason']][] = $row["from"] - $row["to"];
        $array = array_map('array_sum', $array);

        foreach ($array as $key => $number) {
         echo "<td>" .round($number, 1). "</td>"
```

the problem is that if some "reason" is missing for some person, subarray is empty and echo wont print . so my table is wrong

[here is my table and output of  print_r( $array) before $array = array_map... and also correct and wrong results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Snuol.png)
reason2 and reason3 are missing for user1. and reason1 is missing for user2. so after last FOREACH key of array is missing and echo will not print

i simply need sum of same reasons for each users

Comment: from where will I have $row["from"]?

Comment: Please add clarifying details your question and possibly show sample input and expected output.